# DynamoDB: Value provided in ExpressionAttributeNames unused in expressions: keys: {#date}

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update an item by changing value of `isRelevant` to `true`:

```js
       var params = {
              TableName: "test",
              Key: {
                  "#date": data.Items[i].date.N,
                  "accountid": data.Items[i].accountid.S
              },
              UpdateExpression: "set #uu = :x",
              ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                  ":x": {"BOOL": false}
              },
              ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                   '#uu': "isRelevant",
                   '#date': "date"
              }
          };
          
          docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
              if (err) console.log(err);
              else {
                  console.log('worked');
              }
          });
```

What is wrong in this code? I tried all possible ways, but still not working!

Comment: Are you getting any error ? 
Did you try only providing false instead of {"BOOL": false}

Comment: if isRelevant is map then you have to use below syntex
SET myMap.#key = :value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use attribute name mapping for your keys in dynamo.

At the moment you params read like you have a key called '#date' and that you've randomly declared an attribute called '#date' that you're not using.

Instead try:

```
var params = {
  TableName: "test",
  Key: { "date": data.Items[i].date, "accountid": data.Items[i].accountid },
  UpdateExpression: "set #uu = :x",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":x": false },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#uu': "isRelevant" }
};
```

Also- when using DynamoDB.DocumentClient, you should use JSON values and it'll deal with the marshalling info the dynamo typed format.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. `[ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema]`

Comment: Ok- well that's the next error :) does you table have keys date/accountid. Can you confirm that date.N and amountid.S both have values in a log (noting my comment that documentclient marshalls for you so you wouldn't normally get the .S and .N type hints)

Comment: Yes, they have. They have values.

Comment: And are they correctly typed? That error you've copied in means that the values of `Key` do not match the partition/sort keys of your table, either because a) they're not named 'date' and 'accountid', b) because you only have a partition key, c) because the values you're putting in are not matching the type or are null/undefined, d) you're not using `DynamoDB.DocumentClient`. Can you copy the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(params))` so we can keep debugging?

Answer (score 3):

If your `date` id not `Key` in dynamoDB than you have to use in `ConditionExpression`

Example :

```
let queryParams = {
      TableName: "test",
      Key: {
        'accountid': data.Items[i].accountid
      },
      UpdateExpression: "set #uu = :x",
      ConditionExpression: 'date = :date',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':x': false,
        ':date': data.Items[i].date,
      },
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#uu': "isRelevant"
   }
};
```

Comment: Note that you won't be able to use `ConditionExpression: 'date = :date'` because `date` is a reserved keyword. You'd have to alias `date` in ExpressionAttributeNames.