# The provided key element does not match the schema - updateItem

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

```
      var params = {
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#AT": "date"
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":t": {
              BOOL: false
            }
          },
          Key: {
            "#AT": {
              N: data.Items[i].date.N
            },
            "accountid": {
              S: data.Items[i].accountid.S
            }
          },
          ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
          TableName: "tab",
          UpdateExpression: "SET #AT = :t"
        }
        db.updateItem(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else {
            //console.log(data);
          }
        });
```

What is happening is that the code is not working. It gives me this error:

> message: 'The provided key element does not match the schema'

This is what is in table details:

> Primary partition key - date (Number)
>
> Primary sort key  -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got a composite key (date + accountid) in your params, but your table is only configured with a partition key.

Either use this:

```
  var params = {
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":t": { BOOL: false }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#at": "isRelevant",
    },
    Key: {
      "date": { N: data.Items[i].date.N }
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
    TableName: "tab",
    UpdateExpression: "SET #at = :t"
  }
  db.updateItem(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      //console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

Or, if you expected to use `accountid` as a sort key, then you'll need to rebuild your table.

Comment: n.b. I also corrected the attribute name from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52958274/dynamodb-value-provided-in-expressionattributenames-unused-in-expressions-keys - as I recognised the params.

Comment: That means that data.Items was not defined as an array ahead of you using the params.